# How to best save model and write summary during hyper-parameter tuning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

What is the best approach to save model and write session for each run, during hyperparameter tuning? Currently I have a bunch of models and summaries saved under 'training' and 'validation' directories, and I dunno which is generated from which hyperparameters. It is also hard to identify which model generated the best result for the validation set.

The tensorboard graph looks rather messy. Is there a clean way of logging and inspecting runs (from hyperparameter tuning)? Any tricks or methods I don't know about that makes it easy? Or would you guys recommend to use mlflow, comet and others. Thanks in advance!

[image: tensorboard graph]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any of the tools you mentioned but here's how I implemented the logging of hyperparameters and results.

Just create a `pandas DataDrame` or even a basic dictionary with the hyperparameter names and values. To the same data structure, add the performance metrics obtained using those hyperparameter values. This way, the parameters and the metrics can be associated to one another.

Then save it as a `CSV` file, which can be loaded and used for analysis and visualization purposes later on.

Regarding the models themselves, an identifier can be added to the name which can be associated with a specific hyperparameter combination.

It is a simple, non-sophisticated approach, but works for me.